# How to improve query performance sort operation overloads query

Tags: performance, database-design, t-sql

I have simple database which is consist from two tables.

[image]

I want to build simple query that will return

```
ForumId - Forum id (Topics).
Title - Title of last post (Posts).
DateTime - Datetime of last post (Posts).
AspNetUserId - Author of last post (Posts).
```

I tried different scenarios:

**First query**

```
CHECKPOINT; 
GO 
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS; 
GO

SELECT 
EnumerateLastPostInForum.ForumId
,EnumerateLastPostInForum.Title
,EnumerateLastPostInForum.DateTime
,EnumerateLastPostInForum.AspNetUserId 
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
    dbo.Topics.ForumId, 
    dbo.Topics.Title,
    dbo.Posts.DateTime,
    dbo.Posts.AspNetUserId,
    ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY dbo.Topics.ForumId ORDER BY dbo.Posts.DateTime DESC)AS Row#
    FROM dbo.Posts inner join dbo.Topics on dbo.Topics.Id = dbo.Posts.TopicId
) EnumerateLastPostInForum where EnumerateLastPostInForum.Row#=1
```

Amount of rows in Topics `10000`, Amount of rows on Posts `1000000`. Query statistics: execution time average `1600`.

**Second query**

```
CHECKPOINT; 
GO 
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS; 
GO

with LastPostInTopic(DateTime,TopicId,AspNetUserId)
as(
SELECT EnumerateLastPostInTopic.DateTime,EnumerateLastPostInTopic.TopicId,EnumerateLastPostInTopic.AspNetUserId FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        dbo.Posts.DateTime
        ,dbo.Posts.TopicId
        ,dbo.Posts.AspNetUserId
        ,ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY dbo.Posts.TopicId ORDER BY dbo.Posts.DateTime DESC)AS Row#
    FROM dbo.Posts
) EnumerateLastPostInTopic where EnumerateLastPostInTopic.Row#=1
),

LastPostInForum(ForumId,Title,DateTime,AspNetUserId)
as
(
SELECT EnumerateLastPostInForum.ForumId,EnumerateLastPostInForum.Title,EnumerateLastPostInForum.DateTime,EnumerateLastPostInForum.AspNetUserId FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        dbo.Topics.ForumId
        ,dbo.Topics.Title
        ,LastPostInTopic.DateTime
        ,LastPostInTopic.AspNetUserId
        ,ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY dbo.Topics.ForumId ORDER BY LastPostInTopic.DateTime DESC)AS Row#
    FROM dbo.Topics inner join LastPostInTopic on LastPostInTopic.TopicId = dbo.Topics.Id
) EnumerateLastPostInForum where EnumerateLastPostInForum.Row#=1
)

SELECT * FROM LastPostInForum
```

Amount of rows in Topics `10000`, Amount of rows on Posts `1000000`. Query statistics: execution time average `900`.

In both cases i used non clustered index

`CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Posts_TopicId_DateTime_AspNetUserId ON dbo.Posts (TopicId,DateTime,AspNetUserId);`

Execution plan in both cases showed that the expensive operation is

[image]

```
Order by [MessageBoard].[dbo].[Topics].ForumId Ascending, [MessageBoard].[dbo].[Posts].DateTime Descending
```

Order is result of ROW_NUMBER() function,

**The main question is how to improve performance?** Maybe somehow to build query in another way to avoid sort? Change structure of database? I am new in area of SQL.

Comment: you want to sort results based on columns from different tables. Try to create indexed view which contains ForumId, TopicId, Posts.DateTime, Posts.Id, Posts.AspNetUserId with clustered index on first four columns.

Comment: It would be very helpful if we knew what indexes were available on these two tables as well.  Since one simple solution would be to add a covering index (assuming that there isn't one and there isn't too many indexes on either table already).